# Freemarker IF statement for a date

Tags: freemarker

I'm very new to Freemarker so don't really know a huge amount about the language.

I'm trying to write an IF statement to be used within a PDF invoice template.  THe code I already have is the following:

```
<#if record.billcountry == "ZA">
<table class="footer" style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td align="right"><b><#if record.subsidiary == "DBL">VAT No: GB xxxxxxxxx<br/></#if>VAT No: Applied For.</b>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<#elseif record.subsidiary == "DBL">
<table class="footer" style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>VAT No: GB xxxxxxxxx</b>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The above is saying that if the billing country is ZA, and the subsidiary is DBL, enter the VAT Reg number.  If the sub isn't DBL, enter the message VAT No: Applied For.

However I want to change this to include a date, so the logic says that if the billing country is ZA, and the subsidiary is DBL, enter the VAR Reg No.  If the sub isn't DBL, and the date is before 01.04.2017, enter the message, but if the date is 01.04.2017 or after, enter the VAT Reg no. YYYYYYYYY.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, such business logic has no place in the template usually. The template should focus on presentation.

But let's assume that you really have to do this in the template.
The usual comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`) work for date/time values. So for example you could do something like:

```
<#if someDate < '2017-04-01'?date.iso>
  before
<#else>
  after
</#if>
```

Be careful with time zone subtleties though. When temporal values are compared, first they are converted to milliseconds since the epoch in the UTC time zone, and then the two time stamps are compared. So above we compare `someDate` to `2017-04-01T00:00:00` where the last is interpreted to be in the default time zone set for FreeMarker. So I would recommend putting 01.04.2017 into the data-model as a `java.util.Date`, thus ensuring that it's in the same zone as the other date. So you end up with something like `<#if someDate < vatPolicyChangeDate>`.